# Microsoft UDDI Error

Tags: biztalk, uddi

I have a new Win 2008 Server VM. I've just installed UDDI website from the BizTalk 2010 DVD. When I try to browse to the page: http://localhost/uddi I get the following error, can anyone please help?
The website's app pool is running under a local admin account in integrated mode. If I change the app pool to classic mode then I get an exception that it can't reach the UDDI services database. This is installed on a local SQL Server 2008 instance of which the app pool ID is a db owner.

```
<html>
    <head>    
    <title>Request is not available in this context</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/uddi' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Request is not available in this context</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

Line 29:    public void Application_Start( object source, EventArgs e )
Line 30:    {
<font color=red>Line 31:        Config.Refresh();
</font>Line 32:         SessionCache.Init();
Line 33:    }</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b> Source File: </b> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft UDDI Services\webroot\global.asax<b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Line: </b> 31
            <br><br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +11177464
   UDDI.Localization.GetCulture() +168
   UDDI.UDDIText.ConstructString(String stringToConstruct) +26
   UDDI.UDDIText..ctor(String textName, Object[] textFormatParts) +59
   UDDI.Config.Refresh() +1606
   ASP.global_asax.Application_Start(Object source, EventArgs e) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft UDDI Services\webroot\global.asax:31

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +4174081
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +205
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11305670
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4342340
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4961; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS Integrated Mode-specific error may be a red herring. I'm running UDDI Services in IIS Integrated Mode with BizTalk 2010 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 machine, but the database is housed on a local SQL instance, since installing UDDI on named instances (my available remote SQL Server) is all messed up.

Try to focus on the error about being able to reach the UDDI database, which is hard to troubleshoot here without further details (e.g., the exact error message). It may help to check out [this thread](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_2009/f/32/p/16109/32095.aspx) for some suggestions about getting UDDI to work.